# How to get connected block devices on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

What APIs/interfaces are available for this? I think I want sysfs, but according to what various [kernel documentation exists](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.html), that interface can be summed up as "you're not allowed to use any of this, implementation details.", and what little it does allow you to use is completely undocumented.

Specifically I want to find connected *block* devices(which apparently i'm not allowed to know exist, being an implementation detail?), and I'd like to know what attributes block devices have(that I can depend on existing across versions), and their contents.

Just stuff thats actually helpful in *using* sysfs, and yet completely undocumented.

Comment: What information do you want about the block devices? `blkid`/`libblkid` should suffice for a lot of usages.

Comment: I don't want to use libraries like libblkid. In fact my goal is more to make my *own* library like libblkid. I don't want to just copy it or have my code be GPL, either.

The problem is the kernel interface is completely and utterly undocumented :(

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from using `sysfs`, it's just avoided since it's potentially unstable between kernel releases.  You might find some useful documentation under `Documentation/ABI` [e.g.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block?h=v5.5)

Comment: That documentation and olthers there is helpful, thank you. Slightly annoying to find practically all of sysfs is "testing", even if that apparently means "stable" in practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one else has answered this but I've come up with a solution, so answer:

I think the most correct way is to use `/sys/class/block/*`, which contains (symlinks to) available block devices.

It also has their partitions, which you will want to ignore and can identify by the existence of a `partition` file. This file is undocumented, so YMMV.

If you want them later you can get a specific devices partitions by looking for directories with a `partition` file. eg `/sys/devices/**/sda/*/partition`. The file also contains the partition *number*. Doing it this way means you don't have to know anything about device/partition kernel naming schemes, so I recommend it.

Note that `/sys/block` doesn't have partitions, at least on my system, but you're not supposed to rely on that.

After getting available block devices you probably want to do something with them, so to get their *device files* you can read `major:minor` from the undocumented `dev` file and simply search for the matching device in `/dev`.

If you want their sizes you can use the undocumented `size` file, which contains the `device size / 512`. Always 512. Partitions have this too. Partitions also have a `start` field, which is `partition start / 512` on the disk. These are "documented" in [this](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1451154995-4686-1-git-send-email-peter@lekensteyn.nl/) forgotten patch, which if to be believed means these files have been stable and undocumented for about 20 years now. So.. ‍♀️

If you want device *models* you can use the similarly undocumented `../../model` file, relative to the device in `/sys/devices/`. This *might* be documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci-devices-cciss) but I honestly can't tell if thats supposed to apply here or not.

You could also get the name of the device directory, ie `/sys/devices/**/sda` is the full path to a block device, and the name, `sda`, probably exists in `/dev`.

But I wouldn't rely on this, technically `/dev` could have fancy names for things, so I recommend searching dev for matching `major:minor` to be agnostic to device filenames.

---

Some information about this is documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block), but